# Type safety issue when implementing abstract methods from a class using generics + union types [Typescript]

Tags: typescript

I am trying to implement a base class, which takes as a generic type a union of strings type, and then in an abstract method uses a dictionary with these strings as the keys.

The child implementation of the abstract method is not throwing a type error when additional properties are passed to it (but does correctly throw an error if properties *aren't* passed to it):

```
abstract class Parent<T extends string = string> {

    abstract doSomethingWithT(options: { [key in T]: string }): void;

}

class Child extends Parent<"foo" | "morefoo"> {

    /**
     * Would like to error on 'bar'
     */
    doSomethingWithT(arg: { foo: string; morefoo: string; bar: string }) {

    }

}
```

Is there a good way to achieve this functionality in Typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `options: { [k in T]: string }` does match  `{ foo: string; morefoo: string; bar: string }` because it matches `{ foo: string; morefoo: string; }` and the rest of the type is ignored. To enforce a stricter match you can do something like :

```
abstract class Parent<T extends string = string> {

    abstract doSomethingWithT(options: { [k in T]: string } & Record<string, never>): void;

}

class Child extends Parent<"foo" | "morefoo"> {

    doSomethingWithT(arg: { foo: string; morefoo: string; bar: string }) {

    }

}
```

`never` here ensures that it will error if you ever give it the `Record<string, never>` as the parameter. If you give it a parameter that only matches  `{ [k in T]: string }` it should work.

Not sure what other side-effects this might have though:

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=58&pln=17&pc=71#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdhADwAqCuAHhAQCYaRQCW%20A5ggLwIPMsB8CAbwBQQhGISgGcRDQD2AZVkBbXBAAWPAOqN1JABSyADhEaz8YAFyCEAbQDWCZghIBdK91YIAvggBkCACVcWFkoGiIPFgAaBHxcADdcKF4ASit42UYaAG4RLxEUNAwAYQ1kGnIqWgxsPEIiACIAM1lZBoQAHwQGpVDcFrb%20YVFxOUUVdS0dNX0cFisBBAH3aB5shF68Za5V1nWQHBWmTy8UwRFxbzyC1HQEAEF8WXUk0sZyyup8OiwcAmJmq12l0en0Bg0hhdRgplKoNKxtLo9HMFktWkc1hsweidscWOtTucRmJ8kIvEA)

Answer (score 0):

For what you do you don't need generic, because it doesn't cast `options`'s type in child classes and therefore it doesn't bring any profit here.

You can get rid of it. To have an ease of creation of objects with keys you can use `Record`.

```js
abstract class Parent {

    abstract doSomethingWithT(options: { [key: string]: string }): void;

}

class Child extends Parent {

    /**
     * Would like to error on 'bar'
     */
    doSomethingWithT(arg: Record<"foo" | "morefoo", string>) {
        console.log(
            arg.foo,
            arg.morefoo,
            arg.bar, // error
        );
    }

}

const t = new Child();

t.doSomethingWithT({
    foo: 'test',
    morefoo: 'test',
    bar: 'test', // error
    test: '123', // error
});
```

Comment: Apologies, I should clarifiy - the posted example is a simplified extract of the problem I was facing. In the real case there are some common methods which I want to put in the abstract class that use the generic type.

Comment: Then nothing wrong with the code you have. Because with `bar` it still fits parent method and satisfy its signature. It's kind like parent method says I need $100 and child says I need $150, so it spends $50 on own needs and $100 to the parent.